# Incluir "Selecionar todos os Fornecedores" na primeira posição do Spinner?

Tags: android, spinners

Bom dia pessoal,

Tenho Spinner na qual carrego as informações dos fornecedores(opção para usuario selecionar um fornecedor) eu preciso que nesse Spinner seja incluído uma opção pra selecionar todos os fornecedores e aí poder ter a opção de selecionar TODOS ou determinado fornecedor.

Estou usando o seguinte codigo, porem o setPrompt nao funciona bem:

```
spfor.setPrompt("Todos os Fornecedores");
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, forn);
spfor.setAdapter(adapter);
```

desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um arquivo de array dentro da pasta values com as opções do spinner e depois passar esse array no construtor do ArrayAdapter

código do array_gender.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="array_gender_options">
    <item>@string/TODOS FORNECEDORES</item>
    <item>@string/COCA COLA</item>
    <item>@string/FANTA LARANJA</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

código de criação do arrayAdapter

```
ArrayAdapter spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.array_gender, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```